# enable <b></b> <i></i> <u></u> and <br> in textbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, css

I have created a small text redactor, but, the problem is that when i'm clicking post button to post in mysql, all my text redactions( etc.) disappear, i mean html code! Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function formatText(el,tag){
var selectedText=document.selection?document.selection.createRange().text:el.value.substring(el.selectionStart,el.selectionEnd);// IE:Moz
var newText='<'+tag+'>'+selectedText+'</'+tag+'>';
if(document.selection){//IE
document.selection.createRange().text=newText;
}
else{//Moz
el.value=el.value.substring(0,el.selectionStart)+newText+el.value.substring(el.selectionEnd,el.value.length);
}
}

</script>
<?php
//$maxlength = '9';
echo (
'<div class="enterNews">
<img style="float:left; width:1px; vertical-align:middle" src="icons/whiteHack.png">
<img style="float: left; padding:12px; width:20px; vertical-align:middle" src="icons/pencil.png">
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name="changer" method="post" action="index.php">
<input class="enterNewsText" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="'.$entersmallnews_lang.'" 
type="text" size="65" maxlength="149" onFocus="this.value='.$blank.'" />
<img style="float: right; padding:10px; width:20px; vertical-align:middle" src="icons/pic.png">
<div class="biggerNew">'); ?>

<textarea onkeyup="textAreaAdjust(this)" style="overflow:hidden" class="enterNewsTextBig" name="news" value="Enter big news" id="markItUp" >Enter Big news here...</textarea><br>
<input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="formatText (news,'b');" />
<input type="button" value="Italic" onclick="formatText (news,'i');" />
<input type="button" value="Underline" onclick="formatText (news,'u');" />
<?php
echo('
<input class="video" name="video" id="video" placeholder="Youtube video link" 
type="text" size="65" maxlength="149" />');
<div class="postcontainer"><input class="postFontan" type="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="'.$post_lang.'" /></div>
</div></div></form>
```

Comment: Whoa.. You really need to indent your code. It's completely unreadable.

Comment: Another thing: you say the problem is when you insert the text to a DB, but you did not post the code of that insertion...

Comment: Are you saying the full text is disappearing from the posted values or from the input fields on the page?

Comment: <b></b> disappear BUT text stays at it is! so that

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), unless for learning purposes.

Comment: Did you actually look in the database to see if the data went in correctly?

Comment: yes, data went wrong! without html code!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that tag is undefined this means that it will throw an error. If you are in chrome click inspect element console log then you will probably see a ton of errors

Comment: maybe textarea just blocks html <b>Hello world!</b> code that enters with button click? so in mysql it is just Hello world!